# ESP32 is safe enough to control a door lock

Tags: microcontroller, safety, home-automation

It is safe to use an ESP32 (specifically DevKitC) to control a Home door lock using a relay module (or maybe a power MOSFET)?

Supposing that the ESP32 is running a safe and bugfree software.

on the hardware side is safe enough?
I mean will an unexpected and unpredictable event (example:power surge, overheating, anything that should not happen but can happen) 
unlock my door unexpectedly?

Comment: Define safe enough?

Comment: @Passerby edited.

Answer (score 4):

Commercially available residential and commercial locks use off-the-shelf, readily available microcontrollers, and the wireless locks again, use off the shelf modules/radios. There is nothing special about them. The security comes from the knowledge of attack vectors, and good hardware and software design to protect against them. So to directly answer your question, sure it's safe, if it's a good design, but you're really asking the wrong question.